# Find map value with highest number of occurrences

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map<Integer,Integer>`

```
 1 10
 2 10
 3 20
 5 20
 6 11
 7 22
```

How do I find the maximum repeated value of the map? In this case - that is 10 & 20. Repeated count is 2 on both case.

Comment: How is 10 and 20 the result of the maximal repeated value? I would guess 20 is the result you are interested in or otherwise you like to find all repeated values?

Comment: because 10 & 20 repeat in map two times.

Comment: And what does you mean with maximum in your question?

Comment: @Harmlezz maximum number of repetitions

Comment: Just to clarify, you wish to obtain a set/array/something containing every element of the map's `valueSet` which occurs as many times as the element occuring most often. Is this correct?

Comment: By _repetitions_ you actually mean _occurrences_, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop over the hashmap, and count the number of repetitions.

```
for(Integer value:myMap.values() ){
  Integer count = 1;
  if(countMap.contains(value)){
    count = countMap.get(value);
    count++;
  }

  countMap.put(value, count);
}
```

then loop over the result map, and find the max(s):

```
Integer maxValue=0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()){
  if(entry.getValue => maxValue){
    maxValue = entry.getValue;
    maxResultList.add(entry.Key);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not fast method... If I have an `Integer.MAX_INT` elements in map it's will be make worse perfomance...

Comment: @deathember worse performance than what ? there is no other way to do it.

Comment: @deathember yeah there migth be a couple of sytnax errors, they won't be that hardto fix

Comment: That is not a syntax error. If you try to find Integer in map with same value map doesn't return a result to you as true because in two objects - two different hashes...

Comment: you think different instances of Integer with same value have different hashcodes ? You are wrong. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()

Comment: Yeap. Sorry. I think the two instances of Integer will be give a different hashcode.

Answer (score 9):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use the `frequency` method of the `Collections` class:

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```

If you need to *count* the occurrences for all values, use a Map and loop cleverly :)
Or put your values in a Set and loop on each element of the set with the `frequency` method above. HTH

If you fancy a more functional, Java 8 one-liner solution with lambdas, try:

```
Map<Integer, Long> occurrences = 
  map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I was just about to post nearly the exact same answer when I saw yours.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is you  need to write your own put method for getting repeated values

**for  repeated values**

```
put(String x, int i){
    List<Integer> list = map.get(x);
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        map.put(x, list);
    }
    list.add(i);
```

}

So, in this case, map to a list of `[10,10,20,20]`

**for getting repeated values occurrence**

You need be to compare the size of your values list with your values set.

```
List<T> listOfValues= map.values();
Set<T> listOfSetValues= new HashSet<T>(map.values);
```

now you need to check size of both collections; if unequal, you have duplicates, to get the max repeated occurrence subtract list from map size.

Comment: Sorry I don't get this part: _to get the max repeated occurrence subtract list from map size_.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a number of simple methods to do this.

First, we can define a method that counts elements, and returns a map from the value to its occurrence count:

```
Map<T, Integer> countAll(Collection<T> c){
    return c.stream().collect(groupingByConcurrent(k->k, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Then, to filter out all entries having fewer instances than the one with the most, we can do this:

```
C maxima(Collection<T> c, Comparator<? super T> comp,
            Producer<C extends Collection<? super T> p)){

    T max = c.stream().max(comp);
    return c.stream().filter(t-> (comp.compare(t,max) >= 0)).collect(p);
}
```

Now we can use them together to get the results we want:

```
maxima(countAll(yourMap.valueSet()).entrySet(),
        Comparator.comparing(e->e.getValue()), HashSet::new);
```

Note that this would produce a `HashSet<Entry<Integer,Integer>>` in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple method:

```
 public String getMapKeyWithHighestValue(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
String keyWithHighestVal = "";

// getting the maximum value in the Hashmap
int maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(map.values()));

//iterate through the map to get the key that corresponds to the maximum value in the Hashmap
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {  // Iterate through hashmap
    if (entry.getValue() == maxValueInMap) {

        keyWithHighestVal = entry.getKey();     // this is the key which has the max value
    }

  }
return keyWithHighestVal;
}
```